# Datefilter not working in accessdb with vb.net

Tags: vb.net, ms-access

I'm making ledger where I want to fetch data from date filter but it returns everything here is my query

```
str = "Select * from [ledger] where [client_name]='" & client_name.Text & "' OR [company_name]='" & company_name.Text.ToString & "' OR [registration_no]='" & reg_no.Text.ToString & "' And [date] Between '" & from_date.Value.ToShortDateString & "' And '" & To_Date.Value.ToShortDateString & "'"
```

In Access there is already date has datetime data type even I tried using access query builder it also returns all data instead of that particular date range.

**Edit**: after doing some troubleshoot query working perfectly like this

```
str = "SELECT * FROM [ledger] WHERE [date] Between # 10/03/2022 # And # 10/05/2022 # AND [client_name]='" & client_name.Text & "' AND [company_name]='" & company_name.Text.ToString & "' AND [registration_no]='" & reg_no.Text.ToString & "'"
```

but when I integrate with my date time picker to get that particular format, I get an error

> System.InvalidCastException: 'Conversion from string "MM/dd/yyyy" to type 'Integer' is not valid

Any solution for this?

Comment: I am surprised it returns anything. Use # instead of apostrophe delimiter for date/time parameter.

Comment: Or use embedded parameters instead of concatenation - then delimiters are not a concern.

Comment: If you want to include a date literal in SQL for Access then it should ALWAYS be in `#M/dd/yyyy#` format. By using that single format, local culture becomes irrelevant. That said, if you're inserting values into the SQL code then you should not be using literals at all but, as suggested, using parameter. [Here](http://jmcilhinney.blogspot.com/2009/08/using-parameters-in-adonet.html)'s my take on the subject.

Comment: After putting # instead of apostrophe still same issue

Comment: after changing format to M/dd/yyyy and putting between # still same issue returning all data

Comment: Question edited please help

Comment: Solved I just have to repace toshortdate with tostring Thanks everyone for help

Answer (score 0):

After some troubleshoot this is the final query which is woring properly

```
str = "SELECT * FROM [ledger] WHERE [date] Between #" & from_date.Value.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy") & "# And #" & To_Date.Value.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy") & "# AND [client_name]='" & client_name.Text & "' AND [company_name]='" & company_name.Text.ToString & "' AND [registration_no]='" & reg_no.Text.ToString & "'"
```

Thanks everyone for commenting.